# django-nonrel: user's groups-property causing error

Tags: permissions, authorization, backend, django-nonrel, usergroups

I'm struggeling with the 'default' user-class of *django-nonrel* and it's groups-property.
I'm trying to find a specific group by it's name of the given user (a.k.a. user.belongs_to_group(name)).
Sadly, I just get a **'This query is not supported by the database.'**-error calling this method.

I added *djangotoolbox* and *django-permission-backend-nonrel* to the project, but no success.

**Update**: Sorry, I was a bit unclear, maybe. The problem seems to be, that the *ManyRelatedManager* does not seem to work with django-nonrel. Does anybody know, if it should be working or is there some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many-to-many relationships aren't natively supported in django-nonrel.

You might have some luck using dbindexer to support this, but I'm not sure how well dbindexer really works.  Dbindexer generates extra indexed fields that may be required for certain queries.  I'm not a big fan, since it often generates a lot of extra duplicate data.

are you running django-nonrel on mongo or Google App Engine?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried dbindexer already, but sadly no success. I'm running it with MongoDB. As a workaround I installed MySQL aside, but I don't want to use two DBMS besides eachother, if not absolutely needed...